# Changing the input shape of the input given to model inside the model definition in keras

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I am currently having problems resolving this issue.

I have a network in which i feed in numpy.ndarray of shape

```
(batch_size,40,45,3)
```

but I want to do 1d convolution on each row, and then append each result in to a list.

This requires that I somehow can extract the rows of my input, but how do access the input data inside the model definition..

This is what currently have:

```
 def row_convolution(input):
    filter_size = 8

    for units in xrange(splits):
        extract = input[units:units+filter_size,:,:]
        for row_of_extract in extract:
            row_of_extract = np.expand_dims(row_of_extract,axis=0)
            temp_list.append((Conv1D(filters = 1, kernel_size = 1, activation='relu' , name = 'conv')(tf.pack(row_of_extract))))
            print len(temp_list)
        sum_temp_list.append(sum(temp_list))
    conv_feature_map.append(sum_temp_list)
    return np.array(conv_feature_map)

def output_of_row_convolution(input_shape):
    return (1, input_shape)

def fws():
    #Input shape: (batch_size,40,45,3)
    #output shape: (1,15,50)
    # number of unit in conv_feature_map = split
    filter_size = 8
    temp_list = []
    sun_temp_list = []
    conv_featur_map = []

    model = Sequential()

    #convolution
    model.add(Lambda(row_convolution,output_shape=output_of_row_convolution,input_shape = (40,45,3)))

    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="SGD" , metrics = [metrics.categorical_accuracy])

    #Pooling


    hist_current = model.fit_generator(train_generator(batch_size),
                        steps_per_epoch=10,
                        epochs = 100000,
                        verbose = 1,
                        validation_data = test_generator(),
                        validation_steps=1,
                        pickle_safe = True,
                        workers = 4)

fws()
```

Comment: You'd probably be ok with a `Reshape` layer

Comment: @Daniel where exactly do you suggest ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand "how" you intend to select rows, but just immediately after `Input`. -- One important thing about models, you cannot do calculations outside layers. If you have custom operations, they should go inside `Lambda` layers.

Comment: I inteded to do it with the for loops, so storing the output in to a list would not be possible.

Comment: I tried with a lambda layer but the output seem to be the same.. an error message. TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not iterable.